# Higher cup-1 product of coboundaries is also a coboundary?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, simplicial-complex

In the cohomology or the group cohomology theory, suppose $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are coboundaries of arbitrary dimensions,
$$
\mu_1=\delta \eta_1
$$
$$
\mu_2=\delta \eta_2
$$
where $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ are their lower dimensional split cochains.

> Could we prove that the higher cup 1 product is also a coboundary?
>   $$
> \mu_1 \cup_1 \mu_2=(\delta \eta_1)\cup_1 (\delta \eta_2)=\delta(\beta)?
> $$
>
> If so, how do we write this $\beta$ explicitly?
>
> Is a Higher cup-1 product of coboundaries also a coboundary?

Comment: See this post for higher cup product https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268181/associativity-of-steenrods-cup-i-product

Comment: I also ask a related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/326155/106497 in Use of Steenrod's Higher Cup product and the graded-commutativity